# How to free a port locked by a killed process?

Tags: c++, windows

I have problem same as in this question.

[PID exists in netstat but does not exist in task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216881/pid-exists-in-netstat-but-does-not-exist-in-task-manager)

> I have discovered a running process with PID 26376 listening on port
>   9001 and 9002 as when I try to run my program(as a service) which
>   binds to that port it fails.
>
> But when I try to kill it using taskkill /PID it says that the process
>   26376 is not found. Similarly when I try to find the process in task
>   manager with "Show processes from all users" selected, I couldn't find
>   it anywhere.

And the accepted answer says:

> What may be happening is that your process had a TCP port open when it
>   crashed or otherwise exited without explicitly closing it. Normally
>   the OS cleans up these sorts of things, but only when the process
>   record goes away.

I am working on a C++ code and to fix an unknown/unresolved issue I am doing taskkill which sometimes locks the port. How do I free it on next use without restarting the whole OS? Is there any way to free such ports?

Comment: Does waiting five minutes solve the problem?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Nope. Port stays in use by previous PID until I restart windows.

Comment: Questions like these need to name the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: No anti malware is installed. The question I quoted is how the port gets locked.

Comment: Might be caused by a faulty device driver (not necessarily a network driver) so it may be worth checking whether your OEM has released updated versions.  Could also be that a child process is still alive and has inherited a handle to the socket, or that the parent process kept a handle to the killed process.

Answer (score 0):

The TCP TIME-WAIT state will remain for 2MSL , so that the port will still be held open. You can set socketopt `SO_REUSEADDR`, it will work.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t).

Comment: This is about LISTENING ports, not TIME_WAIT ports.

Comment: If  you stop your server  process， the listening port  will  be   time_wait.