# C# kill non-existent process

Tags: c#

I wrote an TCP application and I have some problem with it.

When I run the TCP program and listen on port then the program dead, but the port is still listen.

I want to restart it. It shows "System.Net.Sockets.SocektException: Only one usage of each socket is normally permitted".

So it check the "TCPView", I found the process of the listening port is , so I tried to close it. Sadly fail!

[image]

TCP View - non-existent
[image]

Try to kill process by cmd - fail
[image]

So I want to know how to use c# to close the specific port.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: As Michael says, post your code. Anyway, it isn't a non-existent process. It's a process with no window. It sounds like your code is keeping your application alive when you exit it. As a solution, aggressively killing a process using a port seems to be like amputating a limb because of a minor cut: overkill and not dealing with the real problem.

Comment: I don't know what code should I post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PID exists in netstat but does not exist in task manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216881/pid-exists-in-netstat-but-does-not-exist-in-task-manager)

Comment: Experts Exchange had someone saying "these processes are inactive and marked for termination but not already terminated." Not sure how relevant / correct that is though.

Comment: I have seen that post it doesn't work too.

Comment: There's [another one](https://superuser.com/questions/191416/pid-number-in-task-manager-cant-be-found) linked from there. Could that one help?

Comment: This post want to find out the pid number. I can use cmd to find pid number but I can not kill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sparks a memory from back in the day i was all into tcp servers and clients. I thought the OS took time to clean up ports from crashed or aggressively killed applications.

If this is not the case, it might be because your application started another process, i.e a child process.

Anyway, i think you should start from first principles here, if you are in control of the process you are trying to kill, its better to exit this application gracefully, and not trying to just kill it. Also if this application has a main window you could try calling

```
p.CloseMainWindow();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Also make sure it hasn't started any child processes, as you "may" have to close them as well.

If you are in control of this application, try binding with `ReuseAddress` however this is just trying to make up for bad design anyway

> Allows the socket to be bound to an address that is already in use.

also you may want to take a look at assicoated socket options

[Socket.SetSocketOption Method (SocketOptionLevel, SocketOptionName, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1011kecd.aspx)

[SocketOptionName Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I want to kill the pid by another program. If the TCP application closed, I can restart application automatically, so I need to make sure that the program can execute successfully.