# Why are the PID results in Task manager and netstat different?

Tags: architecture, port, taskmanager, netstat, sysinternals

This is more of a question for the difference in the results more than debugging an issue.
It seems that the PID displayed from the netstat command is different from the task manager as shown below for svchost.exe:

netstat -ab result:

[image: netstat -ab result]

task manager in PID order:

[image: task manager in PID order]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216881/pid-exists-in-netstat-but-does-not-exist-in-task-manager) also highlights this and the confusion that results from trying to clear a port when there seems to be different ports for the same process depending on the tool we use the view.

it seems like Sysinternals is the best tool for the most accurate information according to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/191416/pid-number-in-task-manager-cant-be-found), but why is that the case?

I'm curious what the different design patterns and access rights granted are that make sysinternals better. Might just be microsoft already knows their OS so their own specific tool works better for the updated OS rather than a general tool like netstat and task manager.